# Vote count out of sync for Hot Meta Posts

Tags: bug, community-bulletin

Observe:

[image: Screenshot of a really, really big problem]

Either the 3 doesn't mean question score (in which case, what *does* it mean?), or this is wrong!

*(Caching? Caching.)*

Comment: caching probably

Comment: Yeah, look. Caching.

Comment: @Code: Yeah that

Comment: However, that is a feature request to remove the vote count if they're going to be out-of-date most of the time anyway, which is different from a bug report as this is...

Comment: Bug: numbers are wrong. Solution: hide the numbers.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Meh, close enough.